# LiveAuthClient InitializeAsync hangs

Tags: c#, live, windows-store, windows-live, live-sdk

I am having trouble with a demo from msdn

[The demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh968445.aspx)

On the method `updateUserName`:

```
public static async Task updateUserName(TextBlock userName, Boolean signIn)
        {
            try
            {
                // Open Live Connect SDK client.
                LiveAuthClient LCAuth = new LiveAuthClient();
                LiveLoginResult LCLoginResult = await LCAuth.InitializeAsync();
                try
                {
                    //this is never reached
                    LiveLoginResult loginResult = null;
                    if (signIn)
                    ......
```

the code hangs at ht `InitialuzeAsync()` method and never enters the try statement. Can someone who has used the live SDK please tell me what migh be wrong? The code is a direct copy-paste from the demo and the live SDK was installed via NuGet on VS2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have to associate your app with the store to use this feature, or else it hangs. After associating it, everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

I predict that you are calling `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result` somewhere further up your call stack. As I describe on my blog, you are [causing a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) because the `await` is attempting to resume on the UI thread.

The correct solution is to use `await` "all the way", which is one of the best practices I describe in [my article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). If you have a situation where you think you "can't" use `await`, then take a look at my [`async`/OOP blog series](http://blog.stephencleary.com/search/label/async%20oop), which describes various code patterns for `async` code, most notably [constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) and [properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html).

Comment: the (full)code I am using is in the link I provided. I checked it and there is no Task.Wait, nor Task<T>.Result. By hangs I didn't mean that the app freezes - it is still responsive. Just the LCAuth.InitializeAsync() never actually finishes.